# Align two objects with css position:absolute; (without fixed margin-left or left properties)

Tags: css, position, css-float, alignment

I have the following problem with css lines (again lol). Now the problem is in the alignment of two objects within a '<*li*>' .. (side by side) want to do without using the margin-left. Follows the file fiddle, so are willing to help me :)

Problem faced
[image: Problem faced]

[image: Do I need... without fixed margin-left or left properties) :)]
Do I need... without fixed margin-left or left properties)
[Here] http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/69/

```
.frdName{
margin-top:-10px;
top:50%;
/*margin-left:65px;*/
 font-weight: bold;
font-family:'Verdana', cursive;
font-size: 15px;
color: gray;
float:left;
position:absolute;
```

}

Comment: why not using margin-left? Does it mean you don't want to use padding-left as well?

Comment: Thanks for your time buddy! I do not intend to use as my image can increase at any time during the project. Being goes like text will overlap with the image seen above - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use `margin-left` you can use `position`:

In your `li` elements you have to put the follow CSS rules:

```
.contactList > li { position: relative; }

.contactList > li > span:nth-child(2) {
   position: absolute;
   left: value; /*(e.g. 70px)*/
}
```

I put `span:nth-child(2)` because in your HTML code your second `span` element always have the text.

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T6KrE/71/)

Cheers,
Leo

Comment: Hey Leo fantastic again! I gained super powers in a single shot! lol. Now I can use the chat! :) Thanks for the solution!

Comment: one last question before I go to sleep ... this is a good practice to do this? Using Left? And when my image boost?

Comment: following example of how I'm thinking [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/T6KrE/73/) . I want to make my code as dynamic and flexible as possible ... to avoid future headaches :)

Comment: I've seen your code and you have much redundance. No offense but I think you should first read some CSS manual. One believes that CSS is intuitive but has certain aspects that are a bit complicated. If you know the base, you can do what you want. If you speak spanish [this is a great CSS book](http://www.librosweb.es/css/). Cheers, Leo

Comment: No problems .. I'm back-end developer (c #, java, android) handles the logic. I will not venture into this now, I am studying a lot about jquery and selectors. anyway thanks, I'll find someone who supported me with this problem, which has more patience :) Thank you for your time

Comment: THe good practice is to never use `position: absolute` or only when everything else fails and you've total control on its size so you can avoid overlaps. Here `display: table-cell` (with `display: table` on parent: CSS table layout ; entirely different from unsemantic HTML table layout), `display: inline-block` or `float: left` would've to be considered depending on other constraints

Comment: This is my new solution, for this cause. [Here jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/Vqu7n/3/) - Thanks for all{};